# Accessing a set of pointers

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
class obj140{
    public:
     int x; 
     explicit obj140(int y):x(y){   }

     bool operator<(const obj140& rhs) const{
          return x < rhs.x;
     }
};

int main() {
     obj140 * wtf = new obj140[5] {obj140(1),obj140(1),obj140(3),obj140(4),obj140(5)};
     std::set<obj140> orm(wtf,wtf+5);
}
```

Is this possible? like copying pointers to a set? I have no errors but  I have no idea on how to access it though.

How do i print out the values from `orm` set?

Comment: I am just simply wondering if it's alright to copy dynamically allocated objects to a set.

Comment: @zenith Because he's trying to learn. Carlo, you've written it. Run it and see what it does. Step through it if you have a debugger handy.

Comment: @user4581301 i get no errors when i compile, but i cant seem to access the values from the set.

Comment: @CarloBrew you havent shown us your attempt to *access* the set objects? How are you doing this, what happens that makes you think it doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code slightly to make what's going on easier to see and as an example of one way to get a look at the items stored in the `set`.

```
class obj140
{
public:
    int x;
    explicit obj140(int y) :x(y)
    {
    }

    bool operator<(const obj140& rhs) const
    {
        return x < rhs.x;
    }

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    obj140 * wtf = new obj140[5]
    { obj140(1), obj140(1), obj140(3), obj140(4), obj140(5) };

    std::set<obj140> orm(wtf, wtf + 5);

    for (auto it = orm.begin(); it != orm.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->print();
    }
    delete[] wtf; //edit. Forgot to clean up the pointer.
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
4
5
```

What you are doing works and loaded the `set`. Since `set`s only store unique values (and order them, which makes for a great quickie sort if you need one) the second add of `obj140(1)` got discarded.

Comment: Ooooo you used an iterator. If it's discarded, is it destroyed?

Comment: The iterator can pass out of scope without affecting the contents of the set. You can have a bunch of iterators all running on the same container simultaneously. Just don't change the container while you're iterating. The results are bad. Note: Since orm was declared to contain `obj140` and not `obj140*` orm holds copies of wtf's elements.